# Why is this not absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Need to show if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n \over \sqrt {n(n+1)}}$ is absolutely convergent or conditional convergent.

I tried to solve this one as below.

$|{(-1)^n \over \sqrt {n(n+1)}}|={1 \over \sqrt {n(n+1)}}={1 \over \sqrt {n^{2}+n}}<{n \over \sqrt {n^{2}+n}}$

The last term coverges to 1, so I thought this one should be absolutely convergent.

But the answer is that this one should be conditional convergent.

What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Before even trying a proof you might see that each term is very nearly $1/n$ in absolute value. Then what you know about the harmonic series should help.

Answer (score 5):

It is conditionally convergent as an alternating series with the $n^{th}$ term decreasing to $0$, but not absolutely convergent since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n| \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n+1}=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$\because \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n(n+1)}}$

is convergent by Alternating series test since the terms are decreasing with alternate signs.

But $\lvert \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\rvert=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

Hence the given series is confitionally convergent.

Comment: Hmm, this presentation is very debatable... You can use equivalents for comparing series only for positive terms, using them for alternating test is wrong. For instance $(-1)^n/\sqrt{n^2+10n\sin(n)+20}\sim\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ but original series does not verifiy alternating series test (not decreasing !).

Comment: You are correct but here I just used the fact that $n+1$ can be replaced by $n$  if $n$ is large.

Comment: Alternating series test applies to the original series directly...why bother replacing it by $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? And you have a misplaced absolute value.

Comment: @trisct.....I understood my mistake now. Fixed it now. Thanks.